# How can i resolve the header problem in backpack for laravel?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have the same problem as this person and I can't solve it. https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/2153

Comment: this should be closed as its the upstream issue and to fix it you should just upgrade the backpack version :)

Comment: I am using the latest version (4.1), for that reason I have mentioned it again. When the content is scrollable, that is, it has a height greater than that of the side menu, that happens. Otherwise it works, but in these cases it does not work. 
So the latest version still doesn't work. I do not know if the 4.0 previous versions if they work